# Ignore element in width

Tags: css

I'm making a menu that hides information in the buttons. Take a look at the demo code:

```css
ul{
  list-style: none;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
}
li{
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  clear: both;
  border-radius: 20px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
  min-width: 0%;
  margin-bottom: 10px;

  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
li > span{
  color: gray;
  margin-left: 5px;
  opacity: 0;

  transition: opacity 0.3s ease;
}
li:hover{
  min-width: 100%;
}
li:hover > span{
  opacity: 1;
}

*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>FOO<span>BAR</span></li>
  <li>BUTTON<span>More info</span></li>
</ul>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/g8wn74xe/

The `li` tags should ignore the text in the span as if they are not there (when calculating the width). Is it possible to achieve this effect?

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you want.

Comment: You mean like this - https://jsfiddle.net/g8wn74xe/2/?

Comment: @SleekGeek In the demo, there shouldn't be the extra empty space next to the button text when it's not hovered. Similar to when you set an element to `position: absolute` the width isn't included in its parent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `position: absolute` (and a few other tweaks) to prevent the `<span>` from affecting layout:

```css
ul{
    list-style: none;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 10px;
}
li{
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
    clear: both;
    border-radius: 20px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 10px;
    min-width: 0%;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
li > span{
    color: gray;
    margin-left: 5px;
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    white-space: nowrap;
    
    transition: opacity 0.3s ease;
}
li:hover{
    min-width: 100%;
}
li:hover > span{
    opacity: 1;
}

*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>FOO<span>BAR</span></li>
    <li>BUTTON<span>More info</span></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Nice. This is exactly the solution I was looking for! Especially you made it such that the text doesn't wrap.

Comment: Thanks for that note, Paulie_D. I've edited the answer to include the solution inline.

Answer (score 4):

Set the span `font-size` to `0` and re-set it on hover

```css
ul{
    list-style: none;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 10px;
}
li{
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
    clear: both;
    border-radius: 20px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 10px;
    min-width: 0%;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
li > span{
    color: gray;
    margin-left: 5px;
    opacity: 0;
    font-size:0;
    
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
li:hover{
    min-width: 100%;
}
li:hover > span{
    opacity: 1;
    font-size:inherit;
}

*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>FOO<span>BAR</span></li>
    <li>BUTTON<span>More info</span></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This is similar to one of my attempts where I set the span to `display: none`. Works well, but the animation isn't smooth.

Comment: That's because you can't animate the display property.

Comment: Yes I'm aware of that. But animating the font size doesn't yield a smooth transition either.

Comment: Looks pretty smooth to me but you could hard-code the hover value.

Comment: Apparently I'm blind. It wasn't in your description so I assumed you didn't change it.

Answer (score 2):

You can change the font from 0 to back to the original size. Also, change your transition to all instead of just opacity so that the font size will also animate and it won't make the animation choppy.

**CSS**

```
li > span {
   font-size: 0;                /* <-- Change the font-size to 0 */ 
   transition: all 0.3s ease;   /* <-- Change to 'all' */ 
}

li:hover > span {
  font-size: 16px;              /* <-- Change font-size back */ 
}
```

```css
ul{
    list-style: none;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 10px;
}
li{
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
    clear: both;
    border-radius: 20px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 10px;
    min-width: 0%;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
li > span{
    color: gray;
    margin-left: 5px;
    opacity: 0;
    font-size: 0;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
li:hover{
    min-width: 100%;
}
li:hover > span{
    opacity: 1;
    font-size: 16px;
}

*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>FOO<span>BAR</span></li>
    <li>BUTTON<span>More info</span></li>
</ul>
```